# Mostrar dato/dirección de memoria de punteros en C

Tags: c, punteros

tengo poco estudiando C y siguiendo un tutorial me ha surgido una duda:
el primer ejemplo que vi de punteros es algo as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int n = 5;
int *p_n;

p_n = &n;
printf("Numero: %i", *p_n);

printf("Direccion: %p", p_n);
return 0;
```

El primer printf imprime el numero y el segundo la dirección, así fue como entendí los punteros, con el * imprime el valor y sin el * imprime la dirección. Pero más adelante en el curso hace un ejercicio un poco más complejo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char nombre[20], *p_nombre;
int longitud;

strcpy(nombre,"Alejandro");
longitud = strlen(nombre);
p_nombre = malloc((longitud+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(p_nombre,nombre);
printf("Nombre: %s",p_nombre);

return 0;

}
```

y aquí es al revés, sin el * en el printf imprime el nombre, y con * imprime la dirección de memoria, lo cual me lleva a mi duda, no entiendo por qué es así o si hay algo que no estoy comprendiendo bien de cómo se muestra el dato y cuándo la dirección de memoria, no debería imprimir la dirección de memoria por no tener *? saludos.

Answer (score 2):

como estas?
La diferencia entre uno y otro es que en el primer ejemplo estas utilizando int, y en el otro vector de char(o String), paso a explicarte porque:

Ejemplo 1)

Al crear una variable de tipo int llamada n, estas creando un contenedor en memoria que almacena un valor,  usemos el mismo ejemplo y usemos el numero 5.
Al crear un puntero que apunta a un int llamado p_n(para que el puntero apunte hay que asignarle la memoria de la variable a la que apunta), para eso utilizamos la siguiente linea:

```
p_n = &n;
```

Esto almacena la direccion de n en la variable tipo puntero a int p_n.

Cuando utilizamos

```
printf("%d",n);
```

estamos pasandole el contenido de n, que en nuestro caso seria el numero 5.

2) Al utilizar

```
printf("%p",p_n);
```

tambien estamos pasandole el contenido de p_n, pero en este caso el contenido de p_n es la direccion de n, por eso imprime una direccion de memoria.

3) Al utilizar

```
printf("%d",*p_n);
```

estamos pidiendo pasandole lo apuntado por p_n, es decir, el contenido de lo que contiene la dirección de memoria almacenada en p_n(en este caso, como tiene almacenada la direccion de n, estamos pidiendo el contenido de n).
 .

Ejemplo 2)

En el caso de vectores, funciona un poco diferente.

Al declarar un vector (en este caso vector de char o String), el nombre del vector contiene la dirección del primer elemento del mismo(en este caso la direccion en memoria del primer caracter), y como para que printf imprima un String hay que pasarle una direccion de memoria de inicio del vector, se le pasa solo el nombre del String.

```
printf("%s",nombre);
```

¿Como sabe printf cuando debe dejar de leer los caracteres? por el \0 que se coloca al final de cada String.

Espero que hayas entendido ya que es un poco engorroso explicar bien punteros en un simple texto.

Saludos !

Answer (score 2):

> ... y con * imprime la dirección de memoria.

Totalmente **falso**. El operador `*` **siempre** indirecciona el puntero. Y en tu segundo ejemplo, dicho operador **no aparece**.

Tu comprensión de los punteros es **correcta**. Lo que no estás entendiendo es lo que espera [`printf( )`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

En tu primer ejemplo:

```
...
printf("Numero: %i", *p_n);
...
printf("Direccion: %p", p_n);
...
```

Según la documentación de `printf( )`, el *especificador de formato* `%i` espera **un valor de tipo `int`**. Por ello, puesto que tenemos un puntero, hay que indireccionarlo para obtener el valor al que apunta. De ahí el `*p_n`.

Sin embargo, `%p` espera **un puntero**. No es necesario hacer nada, puesto que `p_n` es justamente eso, un puntero.

En tu segundo ejemplo:

```
printf("Nombre: %s",p_nombre);
```

El *especificador de formato* `%s`, como ya habrás adivinado, espera **un puntero**. Y por ello, tampoco es necesario indireccionar nada: le pasamos el puntero *tal cual*.